# How do I write-host a single property of an element in a powershell array?

Tags: powershell, write-host

I queried Office365 for a list of all users that match the displayName of *Chris*.

I'd like to prompt the user for which Chris they want to select.  In doing so I have the following for..each code

```
$tmpUserOffice = Get-MsolUser -SearchString "*Chris*"
if ($tmpUserOffice -is [array])
{
    if ($tmpUserOffice.Count -lt 50) {
        Write-Host "Many matching users in MSOL. Choose which one you want to save"    
        for ($i = 0; $i -lt $tmpUserOffice.Count; $i++) {
            Write-Host $i " "  $($tmpUserOffice[$i].DisplayName) 
        }   
        Write-Host $tmpUserOffice.Count " None of the above" 
        $chosen = Read-Host

        if ($chosen -eq $tmpUserOffice.Count) {
            Write-Warning "Nothing found. Try searching with different criteria or use wildcards"
            Write-Output $null
        }

        Write-Host $tmpUserOffice[$chosen] " selected" 
        $tmpUserOffice = $tmpUserOffice[$chosen]
        exit
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "More than 50 matches found. Try searching for more specific criteria"
    }
}
```

One of my problems is how to get the contents of the following line to complete

```
Write-Host $i " "  $($tmpUserOffice[$i].DisplayName)
```

Currently the output is

```
Many matching users in MSOL. Choose which one you want to save 
0
1
2  None of the above
```

What changes do I need to make to ensure that this value actually writes a value?

<sup>**Editor's note**: The problem turned out to be unrelated to the code posted here, which does work in principle.</sup>

Comment: I think it should work as-is; `$i=4; write-host $i " " $(@(10..20)[$i])` writes `4 14` as expected. Do the users have a DisplayName entered? Are you getting that back from Get-MsolUser? Are you using PowerShell v2 or v3?

Comment: I realized that (elsewhere) a select statement was omitting the data I was trying to display. Thank you @TessellatingHeckler

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that you just need to enclose it in double quotes:

```
Write-Host "$i  $($tmpUserOffice[$i].DisplayName)"
```

The double quotes allow you to embed variables `$i`, and the `$(...)` allows the value to be evaluated before being displayed.

Comment: If this works, then so does the OP's own attempt. While there may be advantages to using a single, expandable string in general, it makes no difference here (and we've since learned that the OP's problem was unrelated to their use of `Write-Host`). As an aside: to fully emulate `Write-Host $i " "  $($tmpUserOffice[$i].DisplayName)` with an expandable string, you need _3_ spaces between `$i ` and `$(...)` - though the OP probably only meant to have _1_, due to misconception of how the arguments are processed.

Answer (score 2):

<sup>We now know that there was nothing wrong with your code per se; this answer focuses on your use of `Write-Host`.</sup>

Your `Write-Host` commands suggest that **you seem to think that juxtaposing expressions (e.g., `$i`) and string literals (e.g, `" selected"`) performs *string* concatenation** the way that `awk` does, for instance (e.g., `$i " selected"` resulting in literal `1 selected` if `$i`'s value is `1`).

**This is *not* the case**:

- The whitespace-separated tokens are *individual arguments*, which `Write-Host` implicitly joins by separating them *with a single space each*.
  Note: this functionality is specific to the `Write-Host` cmdlet; *other `Write-*` cmdlets behave differently.*
- Because they're individual arguments, you actually do *not* need to enclose more complex expressions such as `$tmpUserOffice[$i].DisplayName` in `$(...)`

Taking one of your commands as an example:

```
Write-Host $i " "  $($tmpUserOffice[$i].DisplayName)
```

While this works in principle, it:

- ends up with *3* spaces between the expanded expression values, because `Write-Host` inserts a space on either side of the `" "` argument in the process of joining the 3 arguments with spaces.
- is needlessly complicated: `$(...)` is not needed in this case.

What you probably meant to do:

```
Write-Host $i $tmpUserOffice[$i].DisplayName
```

---

*Caveat*: While **the above syntax is *convenient*, it is not a general-purpose technique for *composing strings***.

[HAL9256's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51679857/45375) shows how to use ***string expansion* (interpolation)** with a single double-quoted string (`"..."`) to **compose the output string *up front***.

Note that inside `"..."` you then *do* need `$(...)` in order to embed *expressions* that go beyond mere variable references (e.g., `$var`) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) for more.